# How to correctly use test-seam for unit-testing?

Tags: unit-testing, abap

I need to cover my check_adr method with tests, the most correct way to do this is using TEST-SEAM?

Here's my code:

```
      TEST-SEAM selection.
        SELECT DISTINCT addrnumber
        INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_addr)
        FROM adrc
        WHERE ( addrnumber = @lv_addrnum_dd OR addrnumber = @lv_addrnum_pbd )
          AND date_from <= @sy-datum
          AND date_to >= @sy-datum.
      END-TEST-SEAM selection.
      IF lv_addrnum_dd IS NOT INITIAL.
        READ TABLE lt_addr WITH KEY addrnumber = lv_addrnum_dd
                TRANSPORTING NO FIELDS.
        IF sy-subrc <> 0.
          rv_chk = abap_true.
          RETURN.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
```

As I understand it, I need to wrap my Select-statement's in test-seam, then write test-injection in the local test class? What about if-statements?

Comment: We can't help on the "extremely low" coverage topic, you should ask the question more precisely, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and help center in general. You have some examples in the official ABAP documentation. In your case, you would inject values for `lt_addr`. Test seams are not recommended though, because it's less structured (kind of spaghetti code) than other solutions like ABAP SQL Test Double Framework or classic interfaces (specifically Data Access Object).

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is here. What you need or don't need to do always depends on what you are trying to achieve. I would recommend that you start the question with a clear problem statement. What are you trying to do, and why?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a unit test that only simulates database access instead of actually accessing the database, then you can do that with the class `cl_osql_test_environment`. It allows you to redirect any database queries to certain tables to a set of test data. No explicit test-seams are required for that. Example:

```
DATA lt_adrc_testdata TYPE TABLE OF adrc.
lt_adrc_testdata = VALUE #(
    ( addrnumber = '1' date_from = sy-datum - 1 date_to = sy-datum + 1 )
    ( addrnumber = '2' date_from = sy-datum - 2 date_to = sy-datum - 1 )
    ( addrnumber = '3' date_from = sy-datum + 1 date_to = sy-datum + 2 )
).

DATA(lo_environment) = cl_osql_test_environment=>create( 
    i_dependency_list = VALUE #(
        ( 'ADRC' )
    )
).
lo_environment->insert_test_data( lt_adrc_testdata ).
```

Now, for the rest of this unit test, every subsequent queries to the database table ADRC are simulated and act as if the content of the internal table `lt_adrc_testdata` were the content of the database table.